# How to force the body tag to contain children

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/17nc164k/1/

I've been searching all evening and had no luck finding what I'm after, so I've resorted to asking the community here!

I'm currently developing a Wordpress plugin that adds a fixed newsletter signup bar at the bottom of the page. As this is `position:fixed` it's taken out of the flow, and as such the issue is that it overlaps the bottom of the page. To fix this I've added this code which creates some space after the body tag:

```
body:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  height:52px;
  width:100%;
}
```

This works well, but when testing with different themes I noticed for some reason on some of them the `<body>` tag is collapsed, it has no height whatsoever. As a result the `body:after` is right at the top and not doing its job adding a space at the bottom. My thoughts are to fix this is to get the `<body>` tag to expand and contain it's children, that however seems easier said than done.

Nearly all the suggestions I've seen say this:

```
html { height:100%; }
body { height:100%; min-height:100%; }
```

Currently on this theme the `<html>` element is fine, and contains the whole page (838px height) but if I add `html { height:100%; }` it goes to the height of the viewport. But without adding that the `body { height:100%; }` code does nothing.

There are a tonne of questions out there about expanding the `<body>` to fit the viewport, but I've not found anything that solves this yet. Totally happy to be proven wrong as I'm sure it's addressed somewhere but after a couple of hours of head banging and no light at the end of the tunnel I've resorted to asking here.

Comment: _“I'm currently developing a Wordpress plugin that adds a fixed newsletter signup bar at the bottom of the page”_ – I don’t think you should makes this fixed in the first place, especially if you want it to work well with whatever theme the user has chosen. Instead, make it so that it can be “dropped” anywhere into a page, and behaves within its surroundings. _If_ anyone wants to display it fixed somewhere, they can see to that themselves.

Comment: @CBroe I totally get your point with this. We really want to offer this newsletter bar fixed to the bottom of the screen though, it's just the issue with covering content. The `body:after` fix works really well for about 95% of themes tested so far, but there's a few that are causing issues like above. For a fixed item this seems like the most elegant solution as it adds no new DOM elements & from what I've seen people rarely utilise `body:after`.

Comment: I don't understand. If the body is so short, then there is no overlapping problem with the footer, isn't there?

Comment: @Oriol Apologies if I'm not explaining this correctly. The `<html>` expands to contain the whole page, currently 838px. The `<body>` contains nothing, it's 0px in height. I need the `<body>` to fill the height of the `<html>` without adding `html { height:100%; }` which sets the height to 387px (the height of the viewport).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The min-height should apply to both the body and the html:

```
body, html { min-height: 100% }
```

This way, both will take up at least the viewport height, but will expand more if the content is more than the viewport height.

**Update**: if the body has no height because it's contents are floated, you can set `clear: both` on your `:after` element.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. Unfortunately that's not working on this theme. There's nothing obvious breaking it, it's basically that inside it there is a `.site-wrapper` tag, and inside that they all have `float:left` which means that the container has no height. But the `<html>` element has the correct height. Body won't expand to that height unless I set `html { height:100%; }` but then the html changes and only expands to the viewport not the content.

Comment: Re: update, that makes total sense! I was looking at this wrong thinking the body had to expand, but if I set clear:both on the after element that does the trick perfectly. I'll mark your answer as correct, not sure if it's obvious it's the _update_ that's the real fix, should be fine I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `:after` pseudo element. Just give the `<body>` tag some padding at the bottom.  It will be much more cooperative and also has better browser support.

```
body { 
    padding-bottom: 52px
}
```

Comment: Hey Alex thanks for the reply. I thought about this too but for me I thought there's more chance of the body having padding on then there is the `body:after` tag being used. I really want our code to interfere as little as possible with the users page, so adding a pseudo element made more sense to me. Also, unfortunately your fix doesn't work as the body is still not expanding it's height due to all it's children being float:left (something I can't change as I need this to work cross-theme).

Comment: @fredrivett: _“the body is still not expanding it's height due to all it's children being float:left”_ – well then you could use your `body:after` pseudo element to `clear` the floats, no? It is the last element in body, so if your use `clear:both`, then that should handle all cases of body not automatically growing with the contents due to floating children. (If a theme used absolute positioning extensively and had a non-growing body due to that, then you’d be out of options though with pure CSS.)

Comment: @fredrivett Try using `float:none;clear:both;` or `overflow:auto;` on the `body` to see if it fixes the collapsing parent problem. Btw, which browser is having that issue? I can't reproduce in Chrome. Just a thought, you could try using `padding-bottom:52px` on `<html>` if you put the clearfix on the `<body>`.

Comment: @CBroe @alex-w Good thinking on this one but it doesn't fix the problem. I've added a jsfiddle now, last night I wasn't 100% sure of the issue but I understand it more now. I'm starting to think there isn't a way to force the `body:after` element to the bottom without changing the styling of the elements _inside_ `body`, but happy to be proven wrong. Might not be possible this though.

Comment: @fredrivett: Just add `clear:both` to the pseudo element, https://jsfiddle.net/17nc164k/2/ (Having a (min-)height set for `html` and `body` isn’t even necessary then any more I’d say.)

Comment: @CBroe: You're totally right. I was looking at the problem all wrong and a simple clearfix would have done the trick. Added that in now and it works perfectly. Really appreciate the help (@firefoxuser_1 mentioned the fix earlier today too so I marked his answer correct).

Answer (score 0):

If the html element has the correct height, you could set the body element to:

```
 body{
    height:inherit;
 }
```

This should set it to have the same height as the html.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Leo. Unfortunately that's not working for me though. I've added a JSFiddle to show what's going on.

Comment: The suggestion from @CBroe is the correct answer. Add clear:both to the pseudo element.